# Need to save ISO_WEEK and YEAR

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to split and save ISO_WEEK and YEAR between two dates in a table.
To get that data I use below query.

```
DECLARE @_start DATE = '2019-01-01'
DECLARE @_end DATE = '2019-12-31'

SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,dateadd(week, number, @_start)) AS YEAR
,DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,dateadd(week, number, @_start)) AS CW
FROM (SELECT x.number FROM master..spt_values x WHERE type = 'P' 
AND @_end >= dateadd(week, number, @_start)) date_part
```

This logic fails on last week of the year where I get CW as 1 and Year as 2019. But actually, CW is 1 and YEAR is 2020.

```
YEAR        CW
----------- -----------
2019        1
2019        2
 .          .
 .          .
2019        52
2019        1
```

Any suggestions to handle this?

Comment: Seems like you'd be better off with a calendar table. The 2 values you're getting back are correct; the last row has the date `2019-12-31`, which *is* in the year 2019, but is part of the `ISO_WEEK` 1.

Comment: I want to save the year in which that calendar week falls. `2019-12-31` falls on 1st CW of 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @_start DATE = '2019-01-01'
DECLARE @_end DATE = '2019-12-31'

SELECT  DATEPART(year, s.Sunday) AS YEAR
        , DATEPART(iso_week, s.Sunday) AS CW
FROM    (
        SELECT  DATEADD(week, x.number, DATEADD(day, 7 - (DATEPART(dw, @_start) + @@DATEFIRST - 1) % 7, @_start)) AS Sunday
        FROM    master..spt_values x
        WHERE   type = 'P'
        ) s
WHERE   @_end >= s.Sunday
```

This first offsets `@_start` to following Sunday and then loop all Sundays from then on.

The idea is that `DATEPART(YEAR, ...)` for Sundays returns less surprising year for `DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, ...)`

Comment: Btw, reading wikipedia on iso week I found this: "Each week's year is the Gregorian year in which the Thursday falls." so you might have to tweak the query above to be based on Thursdays instead of Sundays -- the `DATEADD(day, 7...` has to become `DATEADD(day, 4...` etc.